# Angular JS and Firebase duplicate data error

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, firebase

The problem I am encountering is that when insert text in plate number, car brand and save it, the table shows duplicates even the firebase database is showing normal data.

Procedure to find the problem **(Remember you have to type at least 3 times to see the dublicate effect)**: 
Input plate number and Car Brand, just type random text. Then click on the save button.

[Link to my plunker code, follow the procedure and you will see the problem](https://plnkr.co/edit/7rl9nYml6CTgDVQe1qzX?p=preview)

My script.js code, I believe the problem is here.

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('customerCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.CustomerPlateNumber = "";
  $scope.CustomerCarBrand = "";
  $scope.customers = [];

  $scope.myData = new Firebase("https://sizzling-torch-2102.firebaseio.com/CustomerInformation");

  // PS, husk at CustomerPlatenumber: må være lik navnet på ng-model. 
  $scope.saveCustomerData = function() {
    $scope.myData.push({CustomerPlateNumber: $scope.CustomerPlateNumber, CustomerCarBrand: $scope.CustomerCarBrand});

  // Empty input after storing data
  $scope.CustomerPlateNumber = "";
  $scope.CustomerCarBrand = "";

  };

  // Two parameters, needs to know what its going to be fired upon, and a function that tells what to do when it is fired. 
  $scope.myData.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var values = snapshot.val();
    for(var myVal in values)
    {
      var item = values[myVal];

      $scope.customers.push(item);
    }
    //not recommended, look at "refresh bindings angular"
    $scope.$apply(); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Just tried and it didn't show duplicates.  Might want to reword the steps.  I typed in platenumber:nick , brand: nick, random text: nick.  I then clicked save and saw one row Nick.

Comment: @Nix, I have rechanged the procedure, thank you for finding it out. Try adding more than 3 times, and you will see the effect.

Comment: Ha! Ironically enough i did nothing and came back to my plunkr and there were TONs of records.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you are inserting duplicates, and any time the set changes firebase is returning the entire set not just the `added` items. So you have two options keep as is and change to:

```
$scope.myData.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  $scope.customers = snapshot.val();
  $scope.$apply(); //or you can use timeout here to be safer.
});
```

I generally dont use `$apply` so you can also do:

```
$scope.myData.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  $timeout(function(){
       $scope.customers = snapshot.val();
  }); 
});
```

Or you can use the `child_added` event that you could also use that might be better.

```
$scope.myData.on('child_added', function(item) {
  console.log('child added', item);
  $timeout(function(){
     $scope.customers.push(item.val());
  }); 
 });
```

Comment: Good call in using `child_added`. Keep in mind though that the children may also be changed, removed and reordered. For that reason a full implementation should also listen to `child_changed`, `child_removed` and `child_moved`. That is essentially what AngularFire's `$firebaseArray` does.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem now is that when I insert the code, the data inside the table is not showing up. Below is the code I inserted:  
`$scope.myData.on('child_added', function(item) {
  console.log('child added', item);
  $timeout(function(){
     $scope.customers.push(item.val());
  });`
 });
I believe the timeout method is not working properly.. Because when I remove the timeout and add `$scope.$apply()` the data inside the table is showing up. Strange..